# How to add filter dropdown in header of CSV while exporting

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, autofilter, export-csv

i am exporting csv file in c# but i want to export csv file with auto enabled filter to the headers of csv file can we do this in c# like below image
[image]

Comment: A CSV is a very basic file, where each value is separated by a comma. There is no way to tell Excel with a CSV file it should display the filter.

Comment: You'll need to export your data to an Excel file if you want to do this